# Rhinos Could not load file or assembly System.Core

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm trying some mocking frameworks for c#.

I created an Windows Phone 8.1 project, then added an 8.1 Unit Test Project

Installed Rhinos with the nuget package installed. Trying to make an simple stub test:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public int value()
    {
        return 23;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        MyTest item;
        item = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyTest>();
        item.Stub(x => x.value()).Return(240);
        Assert.Equals(239, item.value());
    }
}
```

But when I run the tests I get the following error:

```
Result Message: Test method UnitTestApp1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Result StackTrace:  
at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateStub[T](Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
   at UnitTestApp1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1()
```

Where is the problem?

Note: I'm starter with Visual Studio and Windows Phone development so please explain your answer

Comment: Do you see the System.Core assembly as a reference in your project?

Comment: Nope :( how can I do it?

Comment: are you using visual studio? If yes then rigth click on the References folder click on Add Reference, Select assembly option then Framework, Select system.core and add it

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013. When I select Framework it says: "Targeting Windows Phone 8.1. All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced. Please use the Object Browser to explore the references in the Framework". If I click Browse.. I get tons of .dll but I do not find any named System.Core or similar

Comment: Rhino seems to look for .NET 3.5 assembles, did you install the latest 4.0 nuget package?

Comment: When I created the project I selected .NET Framework 4.5. The Rhino Mocks version I installed is the version 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because your Windows Phone 8.1 test project can't reference anything that isn't supported by Windows Phone 8.1/Windows Runtime; unfortunately, this includes your mocking framework.

The way I solve this problem is to move all of my unit testable code into a portable class library which I can then reference from the Windows Phone project. Then, create a normal unit test project which will have no problem referencing your portable class library and your mocking framework of choice.