# Windows phone 8.1 RT - ViewModel Unit Test - Mocking Framework

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-rt, windows-8.1-universal

I have Windows phone 8.1 RT app. I want to write ViewModel Unit test.  So I have created Windows phone Unit test project.

I can't able install any Mocking framework like NSubstitute, Moq..

If i create General Unit test project, I can able to install the NSubstitute, but i couldn't refer the Windows phone 8.1 project because TargetFramework of Unit Test project is .Net framework 4.5.2.

Please help me to test my ViewModel using Mocking framework.

Thank you,

Comment: I answered a similar question which might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645092/rhinos-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-core/28649050#28649050